# Bash File Completion Creates Python Virtual Environment

Tags: bash, python, autocomplete, virtualenv

Sometimes when I use tab file completion in a bash shell it pauses for one or two seconds before showing tab completion, and creates a Python virtual environment in my current directory.

For example if I was running a command in a directory containing a single file named `example.pdf` and wanted tab completion to finish the command:

```
$ ls
example.pdf
$ pdf2txt example<tab>
$ pdf2txt example.pdf
This file has text.
$ ls
bin example.pdf lib lib64 include pyvenv.cfg
```

The result is that I either have to remove all these files, or accept that my directories will be littered with mystery python virtual environments. In my home directory, the python venv resulting from bash tab completion just uses `~/bin` so I have random python scripts commingled with my bash scripts.

Unfortunately, I have been unable to reliably recreate this problem, but my sense is that it occurs when more complex files are present (pdfs, docx, etc.).

Because of the nature of the problem I have been unable to trouble shoot through web searches because all results are about implementing tab completion while writing Python scripts.

System information:

```
OS:     Fedora 36 (though problem started around F34)
Kernel: 5.17.13-300.fc36.x86_64
```

A limited recursive list of python files (I'm assuming the venv files are identical each time):

```
$ find . -maxdepth 2
./bin
./bin/python3
./bin/python
./bin/python3.10
./bin/pip
./bin/pip3
./bin/pip3.10
./bin/Activate.ps1
./bin/activate
./bin/activate.csh
./bin/activate.fish
./include
./lib
./lib/python3.10
./pyvenv.cfg
```

Full file inventories:

`tree` [is here](https://pastebin.com/m8hTnEaR)

`ls -R` [is here](https://pastebin.com/URF9vPj4)

Files related to `bash_completion`:

`/etc/profile.d/bash_completion` [looks fairly normal](https://pastebin.com/K1SG9uNg)

`~/.config/bash_completion` doesn't exist

`/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` was rejected by pastebin but header says that latest version is on  [github](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion)

Comment: If you are sure that this is truly related to TAB key (instead of some misconfiguration related to python script shebangs etc. that creates the env at execution) then you need to look at the output of `bind`. You can use `bind -p | grep -v "not bound" | grep -v "self-insert" | column -t -s:` for a better-looking output. You will find plenty of interesting combinations (`\e` stands for ESC, `\C` for CTRL) capable of interesting effects, but none - certainly not TAB - should cause such drastic and complex command execution by default.